# Did all the the -stan sovereign state names appear synchronously?

Tags: names, asia, pakistan, afghanistan, kazakhstan

-stan is a Persian suffix that seems functionally equivalent to the Germanic -land.

Afghanistan, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Pakistan, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan are the sovereign -stan states.

Even though -stan is a Persian suffix only Afghanistan and Tajikistan have majority Persian populations.

While Turkic and Indo-Aryan languages do borrow from Persian culture it seems unusual that the names of their countries would be Persianized. The endonym of Kazakhstan includes -stan while the endonym of e.g. Finland doesn't include -land.

So how did these countries end up with -stan names? Also when did these names first appear in writing?

For the -stan countries in the Russian sphere of influence were the -stan names ever mentioned during the Russian Empire?

Did they all appear synchronously?

For Afghanistan I found that the Kingdom of Afghanistan was declared in 1926 and before that they were referred to as the Durrani or Afghan Empire. The Turkic people historically were in Khanates, Khaganates or Hordes.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: I don't have sources right now, but I remember reading the Persian was historically a prestige language in that area.

Comment: You also have kodakestan = kindergarten, timarestan = mental institution etc.

Comment: Nitpick: "Finland" is the endonym used by the Swedish-speaking population of Finland.

Comment: Turkish uses that suffix for rather more countries than most languages do: https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosya:Europe_countries_map_tr.png

Comment: @phoog but for itself it's Turkiye not Turkistan

Comment: Let's not forget Kurdistan, either, even if Turkey doesn't want it to exist as a country.

Comment: As a side note: the -ia suffix that is common for countries or places in Latin or English, is replaced by -stan in Persian translation. e.g. Mongolia, Saudi Arabia, Armenia, etc. But sometimes this suffix is just dropped in translation. e.g. Albania, Bolivia, Tunisia, etc. There are cases that both dropped-suffix and replaced-with-stan versions are valid, such as India.

Comment: Lots of cities and towns in the US have a -ville prefix, even if they were not originally settled by Francophones.

Comment: In your list of -stan countries you missed one VERY big one: India. They call themselves Hindustan in their own language (English of course call them India)

Comment: Re *"Afghanistan and Tajikistan have majority Persian populations."*: That is actually true - [Hazaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazaras) 9% and [Pashtuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashtuns) 48% of the population in Afghanistan (*"Pashtuns are an Iranian ethnic group ... native language is Pashto, an Eastern Iranian language. Additionally, ethnic Pashtuns in Afghanistan speak the Dari dialect of Persian as a second language."*).

Answer (score 43):

The Persian suffix stān is much older than any of the “stans” in modern Central Asia. It goes back to proto-Indo-Iranian as represented by Sanskrit sthāna- “standing place” (already in the Rigveda) and Old Persian stāna- with the same meaning. In early New Persian (texts from the 10th century AD onwards) we have names like Turkistān “land of the Turks”, Čīnistān “China”, Hindūstān “India” and many others. These names are all well known in the Persianate cultures of Central Asia and India, where -stān becomes a productive suffix for forming names of countries, even countries as far distant as Lehistan (the Turkish name for Poland).

Comment: What this seems to be leading towards to me is that the name may be "close enough" to what an Indo-Aryan would say to go ahead and use. Persian is from that same branch of Indo-European, after all.

Comment: There are actually somewhat older examples of that suffix used productively. The Babylonian Talmud (compiled around 500 CE under Sassanid rule) mentions "inner" and "outer" Sakistan (presumably Scythia).

Comment: @Meir. Could you give a text reference? I cannot find this passage.

Comment: @fdb [Yoma 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.10a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he).

Comment: @Meir. Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 24):

No, the terms are not all contemporary.  Afghanistan is recorded in the 13th century; some of the others appear to date to the 20th century.  Pakistan is 1933, the others probably date from either the Soviet federation or independence in 1991

Also note *hat tip to @jamesqf*  that  [Balochistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Balochistan) is a -stan predating Pakistan, therefore not all the -stans appeared simultaneously.  I can't find a clear date for the first use of the name Balochistan, but it is earlier than Pakistan.

Below I've provided superficial answers to what seemed to be the core of the original question. I'm not clear on the scope of the ancillary questions, but the sources provided should provide a starting point for further research.
Note that in several cases it isn't clear whether the term refers to a *state* (OP specifies a "sovereign state") vs a subordinate political unit or a [culture area](https://www.britannica.com/topic/culture-area)

## Afghanistan

13th century

> The earliest mention of the term "Afghanistan" appears in the 13th century in Tarikh nama-i-Herat of Sayf ibn Muhammad ibn Yaqub al-Herawi, mentioning it as a country between Khorasan and Hind, paying tributes to the country of Shamsuddin.[19] *[Wikipedia:Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_Afghanistan)*

## Kazhakstan

1962

See [The So-Called Virgin Lands of Kazakhstan](https://www.abebooks.de/So-Called-Virgin-Lands-Kazakhstan-Marquette-University/16341607999/bd) 1962 *hat tip to @jan*

> Kazakhstan was the last of the Soviet republics to declare independence during the dissolution of the Soviet Union in 1991. *[Wikipedia:Kazhakstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstan)*  A more complete treatment can be found in *[Wikipedia:KazakhSovietSocialistRepublic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakh_Soviet_Socialist_Republic)*

*hat tip to @default-locale* with minor edits "Kazakhstan" was supposedly mentioned in XVI century work by Zainuddin Mahmood Wasifi ([source in Russian](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus14/Vasifi/frametext3.htm), (no English translation available)). Both "Kazakhstan" and "Uzbekistan" were widely used in the early XX century. For example, the [newspaper was renamed to "Socialistic Qazaqstan" in 1932](https://en.egemen.kz/page/our-history) and  "Uzbekistan" was mentioned in [1928 magazine](https://violity.com/101627668-1928-ogonyok-sovetskij-uzbekistan).

## Pakistan

1933

> The name of the country was coined in 1933 by Choudhry Rahmat Ali, a Pakistan Movement activist, who published it in a pamphlet Now or Never, using it as an acronym ("thirty million Muslim brethren who live in PAKISTAN"), and referring to the names of the five northern regions of the British Raj: Punjab, Afghania, Kashmir, Sindh, and Baluchistan.[26] *[Wikipedia:Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan)*

## Tajikistan

1924

> Tajikistan has existed as a state only since the Soviet Union decreed its existence in 1924.*[StateUniversity.com](https://education.stateuniversity.com/pages/1503/Tajikistan-HISTORY-BACKGROUND.html#ixzz74f7VQh4t)*

## Turkmenistan

1956

See [Soviet Turkmenistan](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/2495577), a work from 1956 *hat tip @jan*

> The name Turkmenistan is derived from Persian, meaning "land of the Turkmen". Before 1991, it was a constituent republic of the Soviet Union, called the Turkmen Soviet Socialist Republic. *[mcgill.ca](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Erwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/t/Turkmenistan.htm)*

## Uzbekistan

1991

> During the Soviet era Uzbekistan was the equivalent of an American state known as the Uzbek Soviet Republic. It became Uzbekistan after independence in 1991. *[FactsAndDetails](https://factsanddetails.com/central-asia/Uzbekistan/sub8_3c/entry-4687.html)*

Comment: Do you have information on Kazakhstan?

Comment: Note Baluchistan pre-dating Pakistan.

Comment: @jamesqf - While I don't argue the point, it isn't clear to me how it responds to OP's question.

Comment: The survey approach used here strikes me as the best way to answer this question.

Comment: The name Kazakhstan is considerably older than 1991, see e.g. [this book from the 1960s](https://www.abebooks.de/So-Called-Virgin-Lands-Kazakhstan-Marquette-University/16341607999/bd). In fact I'd suspect it is at least from the 1920s, if not earlier.

Comment: [Soviet Turkmenistan](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/2495577), a work from the 1950s

Comment: Also pretty easy to find "Usbekistan" in early 19th century German sources. I had suspected Kirgyzstan was really quite recent, but "Kirgisistan" can be found from the 1950s on. Note that this is from western languages, these names might have been used even earlier locally..

Comment: @jan, if you've got sources, please feel free to provide or edit into my answer; I'm happy to mark it community wiki if that will help.

Comment: All these stans originate from the beginning of the USSR, and some from earlier.

Comment: @MCW: Baluchistan is a -stan predating Pakistan, therefore not all the -stans appeared simultaneously.

Comment: I'm slightly perturbed about the fact that Baluchistan does not start with the letter "i"

Comment: "Kazakhstan" was supposedly mentioned in XVI century work by Zainuddin Mahmood Wasifi ([source in Russian](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus14/Vasifi/frametext3.htm), I couldn't find an original and I don't know Farsi well enough to verify it anyway). Both "Kazakhstan" and "Uzbekistan" were widely used in the early XX century. For example, the [newspaper was renamed to "Socialistic Qazaqstan" in 1932](https://en.egemen.kz/page/our-history) and  "Uzbekistan" was mentioned in [1928 magazine](https://violity.com/101627668-1928-ogonyok-sovetskij-uzbekistan).

Comment: It’s 1927 at the photo

Comment: In Soviet times, we called them Turkmenia and Kirghizia. On the other hand, Armenia - _in Armenian_ - is Hayastan.

Answer (score 12):

One additional thing to add to the excellent answers already given is that *-stan* is actually used productively in Persian for other words as well, such as *bimarestan* (بیمارستان) for “hospital” — literally “land of patients”. Or *gulestan* (گلستات) for “garden” — literally “land of the flowers.”

So no matter what the historical record shows about the first recorded instance of a particular place name, the fact that it's a productive suffix to begin with suggests that any Persian-speaker (or Persian-influenced speaker) could form these sorts of names on the fly, whenever s/he wanted to.

Comment: In the Avesta we have already aspō.stāna- “horse place, stable”.

Comment: not forgetting Ferengistan!

Comment: @user_1818839 Is that the Persian name for Ferenginar, the home world of Star Trek's Ferengi?

Comment: It refers to Europeans (Franks), [farangi] فرنگی. You're not the first to wonder about a Star Trek connection. :-)

Comment: Wikipedia says that Ecbatana is "the place of gathering" in Old Persian. (I haven't confirmed that.) But that would presumably be the same suffix.

Comment: For what it's worth, _frengi_ is also the word for syphilis. Probably meaning the "Frankish disease"

Comment: @adam.baker. The Greek Ecbatana stands for Old Persian Hamgmatāna, the mediaeval and modern Hamadān, from the root gma- “to come”, so it is not connected with stāna-.